# Perform Filtering on the client side and search on the server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a page which allows user to search products and then based on the results that come out of search function (based on keyword), user gets further options to Filter the search to specific results (drill down on the results). As seen in this image.

[image]

When user enters the search term and press on search button, form is posted back to server with search keyword and dropdown selection of Product/Company. Search results are displayed on the UI. The search function also returns Categories, Companys, Countries that the search results has. User can use these dropdowns to drill down on the search.

As of now, I am sending these parameters to the server and search is happening on the server, which I want to avoid. I want that server only takes care of the keyword based search, and filtering (using dropdowns) happen on the client side. How can i achive this?

```
@using PagedList.Mvc
@model My_Portal.Controllers.ListingViewModel

<script>
    $(function () {

        $("#Country").change(function () {
            search();
        });

        $("#Company").change(function () {
            search();
        });

        $("#Category").change(function () {
            search();
        });

    });
</script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row custom-box mx-1">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-12 mb-1">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "product-label" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, Model.CategoryItems, "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control form-control-md custom-select-1" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category, "", new { @class = "text-danger invalid-feedback" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-12 mb-1">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "product-label" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Company, Model.CompanyItems, "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control form-control-md custom-select-1" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company, "", new { @class = "text-danger invalid-feedback" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-12 mb-1">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "product-label" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryID, Model.CountryItems, "--Select--", new { @name = "Country", @class = "form-control form-control-md custom-select-1" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryID, "", new { @class = "text-danger invalid-feedback" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-12 mb-1">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="control-label" style="color:#9496B5">PRODUCT</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control custom-select-2" id="name" placeholder="Type here">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-md-12 col-12">
            <h4 class="h4-title">SEARCH RESULTS</h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        @if (Model.ResultItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model.ResultItems)
            {
                if (Model.IsProduct)
                {
                <div class="container" id="product-view">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-12 mt-4">
                            <div class="card custom-card-product ">
                                <img class="card-img-top" src="@item.LogoUrl">
                                <blockquote class="card-blockquote p-3 text-center">
                                    <h5>Product Name</h5>
                                    <p>@item.CompanyName</p>
                                    <p>Product Description - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, solum dictas vim cu, ne his hendrerit deterruisset, id sed doctus fuisset intellegam. Per case melius assentior ea. Vis ad movet dicunt, ea modus tincidunt sea. Populo…</p>
                                    <footer>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-blue-custom"> Contact Us</a>
                                    </footer>
                                </blockquote>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                }
                else
                {
                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-12 mt-4">
                    <div class="card custom-card-product ">
                        <img class="card-custom-img" src="@item.LogoUrl">
                        <blockquote class="card-blockquote p-3 text-center">
                            <h5>@item.CompanyName</h5>
                            <p>@item.Country</p>
                            <p>@item.Sectors</p>
                            <p>@item.NumberofEmployees</p>
                            <p>First Keyword | <span style="color:#6AB7D8">the match</span> | <span style="color:#6AB7D8">the match</span> | Fourth | Fifth | Sixth | Seventh | Eighth | Ninth | Tenth | Eleventh | Twelfth | Thirteenth | Fourteenth | Fifteenth | Sixteenth | Seventeenth</p>
                            <footer>
                                <a href="@Url.Action("PublicView","Company", new { name = item.CompanyName, companyDetails = item.ItemGUID })" class="btn btn-outline-blue-custom"> Contact Us</a>
                            </footer>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>
                }
            }
        }
    </div>
    <div class="offset-6">
        @{
            if (Model.ResultItems != null)
            {
                @Html.PagedListPager(Model.ResultItems, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
                <p>
                    Page @(Model.ResultItems.PageCount < Model.ResultItems.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.ResultItems.PageNumber) of 
                    @Model.ResultItems.PageCount
                </p>
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, as soon as dropdown's value change, 'Javascript' Search function is called, which in turn calls the Controller's action method via Ajax call.